# Is there a best practice for cache busting when html is cached?

Tags: html, wordpress, caching

In my situation, a wordpress install, we use the core enqueue functionality for styles and scripts, and the version number parameter which adds a GET param after the filename, for cache busting. We bump this on changes to the linked file, as per normal. This is all well and good and technically working.

My issue is that our host sets an expires header for html files for 10 days, so the html ends up in the browser cache. The html includes the link tag, which includes the old version number, which means that they get the old CSS/JS.

When we encounter this in testing, we just Ctrl-Shift-R and all is well, but I would prefer not to be asking our user's to clear their cache everytime we make a change.

My 'Nuke it from Orbit' solution would be to ask them to not cache html, but this seems like a Bad Idea(tm). Is there a good method for busting the browser HTML cache from our end? I feel like this should be a common issue and a solved problem, but maybe I'm just googling the wrong terms here because everything I have seen so far is basically - change the URL's; which seems even more of an extreme solution (Take that, accumulated SEO Ranking!)

Comment: theres no way to clear browser caches.....so plan your management around this, html page caching is not a good idea if you expect regular changes (hourly) and a good idea if daily or longer periods. But then your shared host really wants to save bandwidth so they have set the http header to cache. But really on wp type sites, its server caching that most users use, after images, js and css have been browser cached you might be looking at a load speed of 20-30ms to serve a static html file from your caching server.

Comment: So, just confirming I've understood, it's probably a negligible performance hit for me to disable browser caching on .htm(l) files, but definitely a hit to my host's bandwidth usage? In the meantime, my host has told me I cannot (read: they will not) disable browser html caching anyway. I was thinking I could add an onload js function to pull the version parameter off the end of the css file, then compare it to a current version number requested via AJAX, and replace it if different. Obviously wouldn't work for noscript users and not exactly a performant solution...

Comment: exactly, but again not exactly a huge effect on your hosts bandwidth either but spread that over 30-40 sites on the same server (for the cheaper packages). But look your right about ajax, maybe time to upgrade to a vps? I think there are ones out there for a few dollars a month in the US or a bit more worldwide, theres linode